# Minimal clone to get rev count

Tags: bash, git, continuous-integration, gitlab

On my CI system I need to get the count of revs from another repo which I clone.
Therefore I do this:

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN@git.my.company/my-project.git temp
cd temp && VERSIONCODE=$(git rev-list master --count) && cd -
```

This works but can I execute `git rev-list master --count` without cloning the whole repo or maybe not even clone it at all?

Comment: Since you are using gitlab, try its restapis. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your exact question is "probably no".  If you want to use `git rev-list --count`, then all of the commits to be counted must be present.  When you say `git rev-list master --count`, that's going to count every commit reachable from `master`.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if the majority of your history is reachable from master.

(For example, if you use the gitflow branch model, then all release versions, all completed hotfix branches, all completed release branches, the dev branch up to the latest release, and all features incorporated into the dev branch up to the latest release, would all be counted.)

If this repo's branch workflow for some reason does leave a lot of history that isn't reachable from `master`, then you could use the `--single-branch` option on `clone`, which should fetch exactly what needs to be counted.

```
git clone --single-branch --branch master <url>
```

But if you can't limit the commits you need?  In theory, I suppose the `--count` operation could work without all the objects that constitute the commits' content; but git has no concept of a "metadata only" clone.  Any clone or fetch operation that pulls a commit will want the content as well.  So that's not practical.

Your best bet is If the hosting software containing the other repo provides an API that could give you the info.

Comment: For a big repo I'd also recommend avoiding checkout with `git clone --bare` or `git clone --no-checkout`.